# How do I pass va_list to wsprintfW()?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10, variadic-functions, error-reporting

I'm trying to make a custom printf-like function that take the arguments, format then display on MessageBox but wsprintfW isn't working properly, it display some chinese characters, I think the encoding messed up somewhere but I can't see where. How to fix that?

the code:

```
void panic(const wchar_t *fmt, ...)
{
    wchar_t buffer[1024];
    va_list args = NULL;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    wsprintfW(buffer, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer, L"error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

calling from:

```
panic(L"hello, %s!", L"michael");
```

return error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`wvsprintfW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wvsprintfw) function. (Note the "v" second letter in the function name.)

```
void panic(const wchar_t *fmt, ...)
{
    wchar_t buffer[1024];
    va_list args = NULL;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    wvsprintfW(buffer, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer, L"error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Note that `wvsprintfW()` does not perform bounds checking on the output `buffer`, so an overflow is possible. Consider using [`_vsnwprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l?view=msvc-160), [`StringCbVPrintfW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcbvprintfw) or [`StringCchVPrintfW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchvprintfw) instead.

Comment: Otherwise, `_vsnwprintf()` would at least allow you to query the needed length so that `buffer` can be allocated dynamically to the correct length, allowing for output strings longer than 1024 chars.